# UWP XAML - sizing a GridView to the full width of the ListViewItem parent

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm working on a UWP Twitter app, and I'm making use of the VisualStateManager to change the layout based on the width of the app window (mostly for tablet and mobile support).

I've read up on this a bit, and it sounds like `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` is what I need to resize a GridView to the width of the ListViewItem parent that contains it.

However, this isn't happening. Looking in the live XAML view while debugging, my ListView and ListViewItem is taking up the full width of the app window, but the GridView is not. It's sizing based on the content it contains.

Here's my XAML for the page displayed below:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="mobile">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="bladeView.BladeMode" Value="Fullscreen" />
                    <Setter Target="lstFeed.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="desktop">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="640" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="bladeView.BladeMode" Value="Normal" />
                    <Setter Target="bldHome.Width" Value="430"/>
                    <Setter Target="lstFeed.Width" Value="430"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <ct:BladeView x:Name="bladeView" BladeClosed="UnloadBlade">
        <ct:BladeItem x:Name="bldHome" Tag="blade-00" IsOpen="True" TitleBarVisibility="Collapsed" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource BladeStyle}" Margin="0 28 0 0">
            <ListView x:Name="lstFeed" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0 0 0 0" 
                SelectionChanged="LoadBlade" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TweetTemplate}" />
        </ct:BladeItem>
    </ct:BladeView>

</Grid>
```

And the relevant XAML from my DataTemplate:

```xml
<Style x:Key="BladeStyle" TargetType="ct:BladeItem">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="430"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ListItemStyle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="MetaButtons" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontAwesome}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="TweetTemplate" x:DataType="tweeter:Tweet2">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ListItemStyle}" Tag="{x:Bind Path=Tweet.Id}" x:Name="grdTweets" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="mobile">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="bladeView.BladeMode" Value="Fullscreen" />
                        <Setter Target="grdTweets.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="desktop">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="640" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="bladeView.BladeMode" Value="Normal" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

**Edit**
So I just found the `HorizontalContentAlignment` attribute of `ListViewItem`, but since my ListViewItems are being created dynamically when I set the ItemsSource of my ListView, I'm not sure how to set this property.

Where can I set this?

Screenshot of what's happening:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that I can use a style setter on `ListViewItem` itself.

I added this to the styles above my `DataTemplate` and it worked.

```xml
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always set Max width for Grid , so that you can fit in the Grid view

Comment: I need it to be dynamic, though, based on the width of the application window.

Comment: <Style x:Key="ListItemStyle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />

seems like you are limiting width, remove width and check if that helps.
 if you need some space in around listview use Margin.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create an `ObservableCollection<T>` and bind it to the itemsource of the ListView, this way you will create only the T type items dynamically and keep adding them to your collection and all the data template and styling of listview and its listview items can be controlled by xaml.

The main thing to point out here is that do not created **listviewItems** from c# because that can make its styling hard to maintain.